# Align logo and navbar list items?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have the following navbar and included an image of it:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-left" href="#"><img id ="logo" src="{% static 'core/images/logo_footer.png' %}"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'repairs_and_upgrades' %}">Repairs/Upgrades</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'remote_backups' %}">Remote Backups</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'networking' %}">Networking</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'data_recovery' %}">Data Recovery</a></li>
           <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
#logo {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 75px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

[image: Bootstrap navbar]

How can I make it so that the list items (Home, Repairs/Upgrades, etc.) line up with the logo?

Comment: Sharing the CSS you have so far is helpfull. Plus: what did you do so far to fix this?

Comment: Good advice, @meavo, I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

you can change the list css tag

```
.li{
 margin-top:5%;
}
```